# use resilient propagation on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, backpropagation

is there a way to use resilient propagation on Tensorflow? I know there are a number of back propagation strategies. Is there one that is close to rPorp? Can I insert my own implementation of resilient propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rprop implementation in tensorflow, although it would be fairly trivial to create one. You could create one by writing an op, or directly in python by combining ops.

There is an [RMSProp](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py#L50) which is a different thing.

Note that RProp doesn't work well with stochastic updates. The batch sizes would have to be very large for it to work.

Comment: Interesting. Can you comment on why RProp doesn't work well with stochastic updates? If the reason is that the change in the sign of the gradient is not a strong evident of overshooting, one can fix it by considering aggregating gradients before applying the heuristic.. Or is it a more fundamental reason? A reference that show that would be good as well...

Comment: I think it's probably fixable. The decay rule when you hit a sign change probably needs to be adjusted, esp nearer to convergence. You'd have to do that without adding more state to limit memory usage, and also make sure that the steps are monotonically decreasing and square summable.

Answer (score 2):

RProp and RMSProp are quite similar. They both compare the sign of the gradient of the current batch (or single sample) to the previous, to update a unique value for each parameter (usually multiplying by 1.2 when the signs agree and by 0.5 when they don't). But while RProp compares each batch gradient, RMSProp uses a discount-factor to keep a running average for comparing signs. RProp uses this unique value to take an absolute step in the direction of the gradient while RMSProp multiplies the value and the gradient.

RProp works great for larger batches, but doesn't work well for stochastic updates, since the sign of the gradient will flicker causing the steps to approach minimum which stops learning. The running average of RMSProp solves this issue. But because RMSProp multiplies the value and gradient, it's more susceptible to saturation than RProp (at least for Sigmoid and Tanh - but you can of course use Relu or Leaky Relu to get around that).